# Access the state from custom hook in another

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a custom hook that reads and parses JSON object from the DOM like so:

```
export const useConfig = () => {
    const [config, setConfig] = useState<Config>();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (document) {
            const config = document.getElementById('some-dom-element');
            setConfig(JSON.parse(config?.innerHTML || '{}'));
        }
    }, []);
    return config;
};
```

This object has some meaningful information for different concerns in my application.
So I created another hook that just gets the `objects` array from the config object:

```
export const useOptions = () => {
    const [options, setOptions] = useState<Options>();

    const config = useConfig();
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        setOptions(config?.options);
    }, [options]);

    return options;
};
```

This is ok, but if I only want to read from the DOM once then I would need to call my `useOptions` hook at the top level of my component tree and pass the result down to so that components further down the tree can access it.

Is there way that I can change my `useOptions` hook so that I can call it only in the function components that need it, and not have the DOM read by `useConfig` on every call?

EDIT: I could probably use Recoil as a lightweight state management solution, but I was wondering if there's a better way to write these hooks so that I don't need to add additional deps

Comment: have `useOptions` take configuration options as a parameter. `useOptions(useConfig())` for example. I hope this is a contrived use-case, because this seems like a weird pattern to use (particularly `useOptions`). Don't reach for a state management library yet.

Comment: You can use `window` or `global` to store things globally without a state management system.

Comment: Unfortunately something like `useOptions(useConfig())` would still access the DOM everytime I call it. Writing the output of useConfig to window seems like a good compromise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing a custom hook that acts as [a singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Try using [`reusable` library](http://const%20App%20=%20()%20=%3E%20(%20%20%20%3CReusableProvider%3E%20%7B/*%20no%20initialization%20code,%20stores%20automatically%20plug%20into%20the%20top%20provider%20*/%7D%20%20%20%20%20...%20%20%20%3C/ReusableProvider%3E%20)), the implementation is simple so you can use it as a recipe:

```
const useCounter = createStore(() => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  
  return {
    counter,
    increment: () => setCounter(prev => prev + 1)
  }
});

const Comp1 = () => {
  const something = useCounter();
}

const Comp2 = () => {
  const something = useCounter(); // same something
}

const App = () => (
  <ReusableProvider> {/* no initialization code, stores automatically plug into the top provider */}
    ...
  </ReusableProvider>
)
```

So for your use case, `useConfig` probably should be in the global store:

```
const useConfig = {...};
export default createStore(useConfig);

// Always the same config
const config = useConfig();
```